# How Can i create min and max range filter in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

how can i create mongodb query min and max price , based on min price and max price product form specific category ?

```
const productSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  price: { type: Number, required: true },
  stock: { type: Number, required: true },
  slug: { type: String },
  sale_price: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  thumbnail: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "FileManager" },
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  category: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Category" },
  attributes: { type: [Object], required: true },
  created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  updated_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  status: { type: ProductStatus, default: ProductStatus.INIT },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems a bit vague. A bit more info is required, but if you want to do this, I suggest using [Mongoose aggregations](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate). This gathers all the documents, sorts them, then groups them based on what you want them to be grouped by.

It looks something like this:

```
// Model = Product
const minMax = await Product.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {// filter the products}
  },
  {
    $group: {
      // Get min price
      // Get max price
    }
  }
]);
```

Aggregate is a pretty big topic to explain, but it can be very powerful for gathering statistics like max/min values.

Obviously, the comments are there to guide you and are not the actual code in the aggregate. I would highly recommend looking at that link, and if your feeling lazy, just look at a quick youtube video explaining mongoose aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try.

```
db.collections.find({ price: { $gte: 50, $lte: 10000 } } );
```

here 50 means minimum price & 10000 means maximum price.